# Javascript heap out of memory with old solutions not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When i run my dev script: `"dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js"` i get 
 `FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`.

 I tried to add `--max_old_space_size` flag as suggested in many posts but that didn't help.
 Any idea how to fix it?